# What is difference between Oracle Apps and Oracle Application Server?

Tags: oracle

I am very new to oracle, could anybody tell me what Oracle Apps and Oracle Application Server are.

Answer (score 8):

Oracle Applications means software that helps you runs your enterprise businesses such as Accounting, Humans Resource, or Financials. But the Oracle Applications Server is the technology that, mostly installs on the server, integrates others software to work together. It can be called Middleware.

The first example is like Peoplesoft or SAP ERP. The latter is like Apache HTTP Server, Tomcat, Glassfish.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you are referring to products sold by Oracle Corporation, or to Job Adverts for people to work with them.

- Oracle Apps = Oracle E-Business Suite, formerly known as Oracle Applications.
- Oracle Application Server = replaced by Oracle Weblogic Server, a j2ee application server for hosting j2ee applications (including but not limited to E-Business Suite).

Answer (score -1):

Oracle Application server = it is a platform to build any application(web based)
oracle applications = it is used to run the application

Answer (score -1):

Oracle apps is the application using which we can develop the application and oracle application server is an application server named weblogic through we can access Oracle E-bussiness Suit or oracle apps.